# Leakdetector reports leaks once firebreath test page activex is shutdown

Tags: activex, firebreath, jsapi, memory-leak-detector

I compiled Firebreath with the leakdetector option enabled.
The scenario is loading the test page ,
clicking a links on the page and closing the tab and browser.
The leakdetector then collects all the leaks and the output is [here](http://pastebin.ca/2252685).

I cannot make heads or tails from this log.
is it real leaks?

Answer (score 0):

LeakFinder that is in the FBTestPlugin example of firebreath comes from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3134/Memory-Leak-and-Exception-Trace-CRT-and-COM-Leaks

There is a tool you can get from there that will help with analyzing the results.  Last I ran it through there were no real leaks, but it has been awhile since I've had time to do any in-depth analysis, so it is possible that some things have changed.  That should give you what you need to start tinkering with it, though, and if you find any leaks feel free to fix them and submit a pull request or a jira ticket at http://jira.firebreath.org